# How to decorate text above and below a \sim $\sim$, like xrightarrow?

Tags: arrows, xrightarrow

Just like `\xrightarrow` allows to decorate `\rightarrow` with text above and below, I would like to do exactly the same for `\sim` instead or `\rightarrow`

Is there an easy way to do it ?

PS : I can get a fixed length `\sim` via

```
$A \overset{x}{\underset{\mathclap{\varphi}}{\sim}} B$
```

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to get an "extensible `\sim`" symbol, in analogy to  extensible arrows such as those generated by `\xrightarrow`? Please advise.

Comment: In your opinion, what *should* an extensible version of `\sim` look like? E.g., should it be a version of `\sim` that's stretched horizontally, or should it consist of several concatenated wavy wiggles, with each wavy wiggle consisting of an instance of `\sim`?

Comment: Off-topic: `\overset{x}{\underset{\mathclap{\varphi}}{\sim}}` could be expressed more simply as `\overunderset{x}{\varphi}{\sim}`.

Comment: yes, I was looking for an extensible sim, stretched horizontally

Comment: thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code defines a user command named `extoverset`, which takes two mandatory arguments and acts like `\overset`, except that it stretches the width of the 2nd argument (say, `\sim`) to equal the width of the first argument. An optional third argument can be used to fine-tune the resulting widths.

Certainly not perfect -- but hopefully it's a (decent?) start.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for '\overset' macro
\usepackage{calc}       % for '\widthof' macro
\usepackage{graphicx}   % for '\resizebox' macro

\newcommand\xxoverset[3]{%
  \resizebox{#1+\widthof{\scriptsize #2}}{\height}{$#3$}}
\newcommand\extoverset[3][0pt]{%
  \mathrel{\overset{\textup{#2}}{\xxoverset{#1}{#2}{#3}}}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
$A \overset{aa}{\sim} B$
$A \extoverset{$aa$}{\sim} B$
$A \extoverset[6pt]{long expression}{\sim} B$
$A \extoverset[8pt]{long expression}{=} B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice and simple ! perfect for me. thanks you