# How to write the transform symbol for a matrix, with contents above and below the `$\sim$`?

Tags: overset

I've tried using overset and underset, however, the `$sim$` can't match the text length above or below.
Just like the handwriting below:

[image]

Comment: Why not use straight arrow?

Comment: Could you provide your attempt using overset and underset?  That would give us something to start from.  Are you wanting the `\sim` to match the length of above and below?  What if above and below have different lengths?

Comment: For something like this $\overset{r_2\leftrightarrow n}{\underset{r_1}{\sim}}$ we have to put this \overset{r_2\leftrightarrow n}{\underset{r_1}{\sim}} within $.

Comment: You may want to have a look at and search in this document: https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: `$\widetilde{r_1 x}$`?

Comment: @Stephen Because it's a transform of a matrix in "Linear Algebra" textbook, in China

Comment: These posts may be useful: 1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614754/how-to-decorate-text-above-and-below-a-sim-sim-like-xrightarrow

Comment: 2. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544297/stretch-sim-in-matrix-transformations